# Rails model namespace class_name select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models: `Post` `Tag` `Post::Tag`

The `Tag` is tag info model. The `Post::Tag` a linking model.

In `Post` model, I setup that:

```
  has_many :post_tag, class_name: 'Post::Tag'
  has_many :tags, class_name: 'Tag', through: :post_tag, source: :tag, dependent: :destroy
```

Here's `Post::Tag` model:

```
class Post::Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, class_name: 'post', foreign_key: :video_id
  belongs_to :tag, class_name: 'Tag', foreign_key: :tag_id, counter_cache: :posts_count
end
```

my trouble is `post.tags.take.tag.class` will get `Post::Tag`, but I actually wanna get `Tag`, how to fixit?

Comment: In `Post::Tag`, `Post` is a **namespace** (usually a module) and `Tag` is a **class within that namespace.** `::` isn't for linking two classes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider a different naming schema to avoid this confusion. Especially since table to constant lookup is quite complicated as is.

This is a polymorphic setup where a tag can be applied to any kind of resource:

```
class Tag
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tagged_items, 
     through: :taggings,
     source: :resource
end

# - tag_id [Int
# - resource_id [Int]
# - resource_type [String]
class Tagging
  belongs_to :tags
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Post
  has_many :taggings, as: :resource
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

If you don't need polymorphism you can just declare it as:

```
class Tag
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end

# - tag_id [Int
# - resource_id [Int]
# - resource_type [String]
class Tagging
  belongs_to :tags
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```